# Ajax.BeginForm() and validaiton message of model in partial view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

I am loading my partial view in a main view through Ajax.
My partial view look like below. Now on first click my server code fires for validation but on second click in get the Client side validation and my model message shows up in the views. Why in second click only the client side validation occurs?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function RegisterAjaxEvents() {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
  }
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "messageid", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "RegisterAjaxEvents();" , InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "label" })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @class = "textbox" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, string.Empty, new { @class = "error" })
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Userid, new { @class = "label" })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Userid, new { @class = "textbox" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Userid, string.Empty, new { @class = "error" })
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "label" })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "textbox" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, string.Empty, new { @class = "error" })
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="messageid"></div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
}
```

Also i tried below work but now on second click also the client validation doesn't fire.

```
function RegisterAjaxEvents() {
    alert("I am fired");
    var x = $(this).closest('form');
    x.removeData('validator');
    x.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(x);
    x.validate();
    alert("I am again fired");
}
```

Comment: Your `RegisterAjaxEvents` function is only being called in the ajax success function (i.e. after the first post succeeds). Try calling it in the `beforeSend` parameter

Comment: How do i add BeforeSend parameter in Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { ..., OnBegin = "RegisterAjaxEvents();"...`

Comment: I had tried that but in that case also first time my server validation fires and on second click the client validation fires.